# Find the number of nonzero elements

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, counting

How do you find the number of elements in a matrix that are non-zero. For instance, the following matrix has 5 nonzero elements.

```
{0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}
```

Comment: That is not correct Mathematica syntax ...

Comment: Look up `Position`, `Count`, `Cases` and related functions.

Comment: Two different ways: `Position[{1, 0, 0, 1}, Except[0]?NumericQ, {1}]` and `SparseArray[{1, 0, 0, 1}]["NonzeroPositions"]`.

Comment: I think that @anon has sufficiently interesting answers in comments that this question might be worth fixing and keeping?

Comment: @Verbeia the question is still ambiguous. Not sure if it is about counting or finding non-zero elements.

Comment: @Anon I edited because I found no obvious dupe and the ambiguity was removed by Brig.

Comment: @YvesKlett That's true, it actually was. I will vote to reopen.

Answer (score 11):

One can use [`Unitize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Unitize.html) and [`Total`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Total.html).  Fast on packed arrays.

```
SeedRandom[1];
foo = RandomInteger[{0, 2}, 10^6] RandomInteger[{0, 2}, 10^6];

Total @ Unitize @ foo
(* 444089 *)

Total @ Unitize @ foo // timeAvg
(* 0.00950128 *)
```

Some comparisons:

```
Length @ SparseArray[foo]["NonzeroPositions"] // timeAvg
(* 0.0154271 *)

Length[foo] - Count[foo, 0] // timeAvg
(* 0.0440302 *)

Count[foo, x_ /; x != 0] // timeAvg
(* 0.358267 *)

Length[Select[foo, # != 0 &]] // timeAvg
(* 0.439782 *)
```

---

Timing function:

```
SetAttributes[timeAvg, HoldFirst]
timeAvg[func_] := 
 Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ AbsoluteTiming@Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 15}]
```

Comment: If the non zero elements are always `1`s, you can spare the `Unitize`, or even use `Lenght[lst]-Plus@@lst`. How much faster would that be?

Comment: If the nonzero entries were all `1`, then `Total@foo` takes `0.00749397` sec.  `Plus @@ foo` takes `0.092115` sec. because `Apply` (`@@`) unpacks the array. (`foo = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, 10^6] RandomInteger[{0, 1}, 10^6]`)

Comment: Darn packed arrays! There was no such thing when I learned Mathematica, last century!

Comment: @Peltio AFAIK they were introduced in version 4 around 1999.

Comment: @Szabolcs I was talking of the other 98 years of that century. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Very straightforward

```
Count[{0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, 
 x_ /; x != 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to select the nonzero entries and then count how many there are:

```
lst = {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1};
Length[Select[lst, # != 0 &]]
5
```