# Count Column Elements in a Matrix

Tags: matrix, counting

Let a square matrix be:

`mat={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{0,0,0}};`

Get a total for each column:

`In: Total[mat]`

`Out: {5,7,9}`

I would like to obtain the number of non-zero elements of each column (and the result to be in the form {a,b,c}).

Thanks

Comment: Seems like a strange thing to want for a square matrix but `Map[Length, Transpose[mat]]` and `ConstantArray @@ Dimensions[mat]` are two methods that come to mind.

Comment: @ercegovac,  In general you need to `Transpose`, i.e. if the matrix is not square -- without it you are giving the lengths of the rows.

Comment: @MikeLimaOscar You are right. My mistake, missed that part.

Comment: @MikeLimaOscar sorry i didn t specify that it was for non-zero elements. My problem lies in cumulative output. For a single column i just use Count[mat[[All,1;;1]],Except [0], {2}].

Comment: Yes, that makes it a less strange request.  You are most of the way there: `Count[#, Except[0]] & /@ Transpose[mat]` gives `{2, 2, 2}`.  If you might have inexact zeroes use `Except[0 | 0.]`.

Comment: @MikeLimaOscar Thank you very much. This is a very useful specification.

Comment: Is this really a duplicate of the https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38624 ?  I believe that asks for a total count, not a column count.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the simplest version is:

```
Total @ Unitize @ mat
```

> {2, 2, 2}

Comment: Nice.  I forgot about `Unitize`.

Comment: Thanks. Very simple and elegant answer. It helps a lot.

Answer (score 3):

```
Total@Boole[Thread[# != 0] & /@ mat]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 Total@Abs@Sign[mat[[All, 1 ;; Dimensions[mat][[2]]]]]
```